# R forecast.holtwinters in forecast package not found

Tags: r, forecasting, holtwinters

I am trying to use the forecast.holtwinters function and when I try to run it:

```
dftimeseriesforecast <- forecast.HoltWinters(data, h=65)
```

I get this error:

> Error: could not find function "forecast.HoltWinters"

I have also tried this:

```
 dftimeseriesforecast= forecast::forecast.HoltWinters(data, h=65)
```

But I get this error message:

> Error: 'forecast.HoltWinters' is not an exported object from 'namespace:forecast'

I look at this list of functions in the forecast package using this code:

```
ls("package:forecast")
```

and this returns:

> [1] "%>%"               "accuracy"          "Acf"               "arfima"            "Arima"             "arima.errors"      "arimaorder"        "auto.arima"
>    [9] "autolayer"         "baggedETS"         "bats"              "bizdays"           "bld.mbb.bootstrap" "BoxCox"            "BoxCox.lambda"     "Ccf"
>   [17] "checkresiduals"    "croston"           "CV"                "CVar"              "dm.test"           "dshw"              "easter"            "ets"
>   [25] "findfrequency"     "forecast"          "forecast.ets"      "fourier"           "fourierf"          "gas"               "geom_forecast"     "GeomForecast"
>   [33] "getResponse"       "ggAcf"             "ggCcf"             "gghistogram"       "gglagchull"        "gglagplot"         "ggmonthplot"       "ggPacf"
>   [41] "ggseasonplot"      "ggsubseriesplot"   "ggtaperedacf"      "ggtaperedpacf"     "ggtsdisplay"       "gold"              "holt"              "hw"
>   [49] "InvBoxCox"         "is.acf"            "is.Arima"          "is.baggedETS"      "is.bats"           "is.constant"       "is.ets"            "is.forecast"
>   [57] "is.mforecast"      "is.nnetar"         "is.nnetarmodels"   "is.splineforecast" "is.stlm"           "ma"                "meanf"             "monthdays"
>   [65] "msts"              "na.interp"         "naive"             "ndiffs"            "nnetar"            "nsdiffs"           "Pacf"              "remainder"
>   [73] "rwf"               "seasadj"           "seasonal"          "seasonaldummy"     "seasonaldummyf"    "seasonplot"        "ses"               "sindexf"
>   [81] "snaive"            "splinef"           "StatForecast"      "stlf"              "stlm"              "taperedacf"        "taperedpacf"       "taylor"
>   [89] "tbats"             "tbats.components"  "thetaf"            "trendcycle"        "tsclean"           "tsCV"              "tsdisplay"         "tslm"
>   [97] "tsoutliers"        "wineind"           "woolyrnq"

Does anyone know what is going on? I've used this before and had no problems.  I'm using forecast version 8.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of these things are in the `forecast` package. They are in `stats`:

```
> m <- stats::HoltWinters(co2)
> class(m)
[1] "HoltWinters"
> p = predict(m)
> pp = stats:::predict.HoltWinters(m)
> p
          Jan
1998 365.1079
> pp
          Jan
1998 365.1079
```

`predict.HoltWinters` is an unexported function from `stats` which should only be called on objects from `HoltWinters()`.

`forecast.HoltWinters` is an unexported function  from `forecast` which means you need *three* colons to access it. But you should *never have to* do this because it should be automatically found when you run `forecast` on a the output from `HoltWinters()`:

```
> m <- stats::HoltWinters(co2)
> forecast(m)
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Jan 1998       365.1079 364.7139 365.5019 364.5053 365.7105
Feb 1998       365.9664 365.5228 366.4100 365.2879 366.6449
[etc]
```

Same as:

```
> forecast:::forecast.HoltWinters(m)
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Jan 1998       365.1079 364.7139 365.5019 364.5053 365.7105
Feb 1998       365.9664 365.5228 366.4100 365.2879 366.6449
[etc]
```

Comment: I just checked and that is true for predict.Holtwinters, but it isn't true for forecast.Holtwinters. The forecast pdf lists forecast.Holtwinters and stats:::forecast.HoltWinters doesn't work. I get the same error. cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf.  But, predict.holtwinters does just as well as forecast.Holtwinters so I can use this instead. Thank you @Spacedman

Comment: Think I was a bit rushed with that answer. You need three colons to get unexported functions but you should never have to.. See edits.

Comment: Also, I installed older version R 3.2 instead of the current version and forecast.holtwinters and predict.holtwinters was present and working properly, so I think there's a problem with version of R and forecast 8.1. But, holtwinters works fine with the stats package as well.

Answer (score 9):

Use like this:

```
forecast:::forecast.HoltWinters().
```

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when using R v3.4.4 and forecast v8.2:

`hw <- stats::HoltWinters(data)
forecast_data <- forecast(hw, h=65)`

Answer (score 1):

you can try belows code,it will work. you need not HoltWinters.forecast.

```
    dftimeseries.hw <- HoltWinters(data)
    dftimeseries.forecast <-forecast(dftimeseries.hw,h=65)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
forecast_data <-forecast(mydata #data name,h=56)
```

after updating your `r` version and it will work